# PHP Redis Destroy Session On All Servers

Tags: php, session, redis

I'm using Nicolasff Redis-PHP extension(https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis) for handling sessions on multipe servers. So I have changed my session handlers as suggested:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://host1:6379?weight=1"
```

On logout, I am destroying the session like so on one server:

```
setcookie('session_id', NULL, time() - 4800);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
session_destroy();
```

But the problem is the session is only destroyed one servers and not the other. How can I ensure that session is destroyed on all servers?

Comment: Probable solution will be to store session in single RedisStore instance. So that destroying session on one server will destroy on others too.

Answer (score 0):

Note the description of the parameter "weight" in `phpredis`:

> the weight of a host is used in comparison with the others in order to customize the session distribution on several hosts. If host A has twice the weight of host B, it will get twice the amount of sessions. In the example, host1 stores 20% of all the sessions (1/(1+2+2)) while host2 and host3 each store 40% (2/1+2+2). The target host is determined once and for all at the start of the session, and doesn't change. The default weight is 1.

It`s means that phpredis choose destination server by session id and make this choose each time your change it. In your code:

```
  //Both of next lines delete session key in redis stotage.
  //Read from 411 line of redis_session.c 
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();

  //delete current session (due to $delete_old_session = true) and start new 
  //session i.e. select new server and write data.
  session_regenerate_id(true);
```

In other words - you do not need to do anything special if you are using N servers to store session in radis with phpredis. Simply remove the session with `session_unset` or `session_destroy` if you do not need it, or call `session_regenerate_id` if need new session id for already started session.